# Oracle 11g R2 SE run query

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

How do i run the below query inside sql > prompt in Oracle 11g R2 SE

```
 CREATE TRIGGER "ICD".TR_DEL_SYSTEMALERTCFG_CSTLVL
   after delete on t_custlevel
 begin
   delete t_monitor_systemalertcfg a
   where a.queuetype = 4
     and a.queueid not in (
                   select b.id from t_custlevel b
                   where a.subccno = b.subccno
                     and a.vdn = b.vdn
                   );
 end TR_DEL_SYSTEMALERTCFG_CSTLVL;
```

Please suggest.

Thanks

Kaushal

Comment: Could you reformat the query? Try selecting the code and hitting the "Code" button to make it much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

1. Save your query to a file named "my_query.sql".
2. run command prompt (DOS, linux shell, whatever...).
3. navigate to directory where your script is (using the `cd` command, probably).
4. Run the Oracle `sqlplus` command to connect to database.
5. Run command `@my_query.sql` to execute the query file.

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER "ICD".TR_DEL_SYSTEMALERTCFG_CSTLVL after delete on t_custlevel
begin
    delete t_monitor_systemalertcfg a
    where a.queuetype = 4
    and a.queueid not in (select b.id from t_custlevel b where a.subccno = b.subccno and a.vdn = b.vdn)
end TR_DEL_SYSTEMALERTCFG_CSTLVL

I did saved that above query in my_query.sql and did sql >@/root/sesl/my_query.sql it did not exit.

Comment: @Kaushal Shriyan: What did not exist? What message was returned?

Answer (score 0):

Put a slash at the end and exit if you automaticly want to exit sql

```
CREATE TRIGGER "ICD".TR_DEL_SYSTEMALERTCFG_CSTLVL
       after delete on t_custlevel
     begin
       delete t_monitor_systemalertcfg a
       where a.queuetype = 4
         and a.queueid not in (
                       select b.id from t_custlevel b
                       where a.subccno = b.subccno
                         and a.vdn = b.vdn
                       );
     end TR_DEL_SYSTEMALERTCFG_CSTLVL;
    /

    exit
```

BTW : your are not running sqlplus on the database server as root, are you?